# Server request: angular route/url after hash#?

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, http, https

Let's say I send someone by email a link to a section of my web which requires the user to be logged in. For ex:

```
https://www.web.com/serverroute/angularapp#/clientrouteone
```

When the user that has not logged in clicks on the link, the client site only knows about "web.com/serverroute/" and redirects to login form.

Now on successful login how to go around it if I want redirecting to the original full url requested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the prior url to $rootScope and redirect there after login

Or better with an interceptor in your main 'app.config':

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q', '$location', '$rootScope', '$window', function ($q, $location, $rootScope, $window) {
                        return {
                            'request': function () {
                               'do your magic'
                                var magic = $window.history.back(); //just an example dont think this will work for you
                                return magic;
                                } 
                            }
                        }]):
```

Answer (score 1):

your login process must handle it. somewhere in your filter chain, where you redirect user to login page, you need to keep full url, so that it looks like "https://my.cool.site/login#original/url". then, on login form you pick it as $location.path() and redirect accordingly.